# C++ set struct attribute to own address

Tags: c++, struct

I am somewhat new to C/C++, so lets say I have a simple struct:

```
struct item {
   int* address;
   std::string name;
}
```

1. Is `int*` the correct datatype to hold a memory address?
2. Can I just use something like:

   ```
   item i;
   i.address = &i.;
   ```

   To set the structs attribute to it's own address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. In C/C++ pointers are *typed*. You can store in any pointer any other pointer (since it's only index of byte in memory), but you can't freely convert them (you need to use casts). Typically pointer on variable of type `T`, should have type `T *`. So in your example should be:

   ```
   struct item {
      std::string * address;
      std::string name;
   }
   ```
2. Yes, you can:

   ```
    item i;
    i.address = &(i.name);
   ```

This is if you want to store address of member `name`.

If you want to store address of structure:

```
struct item {
   item * address;
   std::string name;
}

item i;
i.address = &i;
```

Comment: I'm assuming the type for the address pointer should be big enough to hold an address (16, 32, or 64 bits). Also, is `item * address;` the same as `item* address;`?

Comment: @James_Parsons in C/C++ all pointers are of the same size. Of 32-bit platforms they are 32-bit, on 64-bit platforms they are 64-bit.

Comment: @James_Parsons Yes, but if you do that manually, you're relying on an implementation detail. By referring to the concrete type (`T*`) or the universal pointer (`void*`) you'll always get the right size. `int*` is a pointer to a integer, not a pointer of size integer.

Comment: @James: Technically, addresses are opaque things in C/C++: the standard doesn't have any concept of pointers having numeric value. Of course, pointers are usually implemented that way in assembly, but other things are possible.

Comment: @James_Parsons Yes, spaces doesn't do anything here: `item * address;` == `item* address;`

Comment: @Hurkyl: No, C++ (and C) pointers are not opaque.  They support many arithmetic operations (which is called "pointer arithmetic") and also can be converted to and from an integer of sufficient size.  Perhaps you are thinking of references, or of some other language.

Comment: @rutsky: Technically, there is no guarantee that all pointer types are the same size, even leaving out function pointers. The only guarantee is that any object pointer type can be losslessly cast to void* and back. (That's in case there is an architecture where pointers are word addresses, and char pointers need to have additional bits to identify the char within the word. There *were* such architectures but I don't know if you could still find one.)

Comment: @Ben: They can be converted to an integer, but the numeric value of that integer doesn't necessarily have any relation to the meaning of the pointer. Differences of (some pairs of) pointers have numeric value, but that doesn't mean the pointers themselves are numeric things; compare with the notion of points and vectors. (although pointers are certainly algebraic objects in a suitable sense)

Comment: @Hurkyl: If you start defining "numeric" apart from supporting certain operations... Seems like a matter of philosophy.

Comment: @rici You are right, but I think James is not interested in such details at this moment.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, if you merely want a memory address, you store it in a `void*`, because that type doesn't have any connotations of being a pointer to a thing.

If you want to retain the connotation that `item::address` is a member that holds a pointer to an `item` object, then it should have type `item*`, possibly qualified appropriately with `const` if appropriate.

(in `C`, of course, the type would instead be `struct item*`, because it would hold a pointer to a `struct item` object)

Answer (score 0):

`int *x;` is used to create a pointer to an `int` so you could do something like:

```
int j = 4;        // create an int variable
int *pToJ = &j;   // create a pointer that contains the address of the int j.
```

For a `struct` you could do something similar by defining the struct, creating a struct variable, creating a pointer to the struct, and then assigning the address of the struct variable to the struct pointer variable.  This would look something like for C:

```
struct __tagStruct {  // start a struct definition declaring a name of __tagStruct
  int  i;
  int  j;
};

struct __tagStruct myStruct;
struct __tagStruct *pMyStruct = &myStruct;

// or C++ allows you to use the struct name as a type name like a class
__tagStruct  myStruct2;
__tagStruct *pMyStruct2 = myStruct2;
```

If you want to have a struct that can contain its own address then you need to have as part of the struct definition a member variable which is a pointer to the struct type.  This is a bit more difficult since in order to define a pointer to a struct you must define or declare the struct first.  Fortunately for a pointer to a struct just declaring that the struct definition exists is sufficient. So you could do the following:

```
struct __tagStruct {      // starts the struct definition declaring a name of __tagStruct
   __tagStruct  *pMe;   // define a pointer variable to this struct type C++ style
   int    i;
   int    j;
};

struct __tagStruct  myStruct;    // define the struct variable C style
myStruct.pMe = &myStruct;

// or C++ allows you to use the struct name like a class for a type
__tagStruct  myStruct;
myStruct.pMe = &myStruct;        // assign to the pMe member the address of the struct
```

If the struct contained a pointer to a different struct type then you could do something like the following:

```
struct __tagStruct1;

struct __tagStruct2 {
  __tagStruct1 *pIt;    // pointer to the previously declared struct
  int  j;
};

__tagStruct1  myStruct1;
__tagStruct2  myStruct2;
myStruct2.pIt = &myStruct1;
```